# Looping through Batched Requests (50 calls each) for reachestimate api calls

Tags: ads, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to do mass reach estimate calls for specific targeting and each api call searches a different keyword to return the reach estimate for that keyword. At one time I am doing this for 300 keywords, which with a limit of 50 per batched request I am doing this 6 times (looping through) and it is very slow. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to do this faster without a loop?

Comment: The reachestimate call is extremely CPU intensive; there's no way to make it faster from the client side, adding them to a batch really just removes the HTTP/SSL overhead in setting up a new API call, the time the call takes to complete on the server side is basically the same no matter how you call it

Comment: ok thats what i figured but thought i would ask anyways, thanks!